How to Integrate Google Analytics into a Java Dynamic Web Project Using JSP and Servlets on XAMPP?
I'm currently working on a Java dynamic web project that utilizes JSP and servlets, and I'm running it locally on XAMPP with Tomcat 9. I would like to integrate Google Analytics to track user interactions on my web application. Is it possible to do it locally, and if yes, how.
When I attempt to create a Google Analytics property, it's asking for a website URL. Since my application is running locally (e.g., http://localhost:8080/myapp), I'm not sure how to proceed.
So, my questions are -
How can I create a Google Analytics property for a local development environment?
Is there a workaround to simulate a URL for testing purposes?
Once I have the tracking ID, what’s the best way to implement the Google Analytics script in my JSP files?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
